# Cronjob is not running for jar file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, jar, cron

I have one java jar file in linux. I have created one script to run that jar file. When I run the script manually, it is running fine.

But when I schedule the cronjob to run the script,it doesn't work.

Below is the cronjob which I scheduled

```
                 11 10 * * * /home/sub/model.sh >> /home/sub/model.log
```

Below is the shell script.

```
                      #!/bin/bash
                      /usr/bin/java -jar /home/sub/myprogram.jar
```

Anyone please help me to solve this issue. I don't know what I missed

Comment: You missed telling us what your program does. Source code would be good.  There's a pretty high likelihood (having seen other, similar questions) that you're trying to launch a GUI app from cron ...

Comment: A normal java program which prints few lines @tink

Comment: Prints to the command line or in an AWT gui?

Comment: Prints to the command line @tink

Comment: Try to log stderr `> /home/sub/model.log 2>&1`  and check your log for any error